# Workarounds for a possible bug in the linearity of FourierTransform

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40432/possible-bug-with-fouriertransform-linearity), except the problem I am encountering is to do with Fourier transforms of scalar multiples of functions and their derivatives.

I wish to input `FourierTransform[a*f[t],t,x]` and have Mathematica simplify it to `a*FourierTransform[f[t],t,x]`, and, equivalently, to input `FourierTransform[f'[t],t,x]` and have Mathematica simplify it to `ix*FourierTransform[f[t],t,x]`. I'm taking the Fourier transform of a system of differential equations for functions `f[t]`,`g[t]`, etc., in order to instead only have to solve a system of algebraic equations for their Fourier transforms, but Mathematica seems to be having some problems doing this.

Note that `LaplaceTransform` works exactly as expected, but for some reason `FourierTransform` doesn't perform the expected simplification. If someone could suggest a solution that also incorporates the distributive property that `FourierTransform` was shown to have a problem with in the question I linked, that would be ideal.

## Example

This is essentially what I'd like `FourierTransform` to do:

```
LaplaceTransform[{a*f[t]+b*g'[t]==0,c*f'[t]+d*g[t]==0},t,x]
```

which returns:

```
{a*LaplaceTransform[f[t],t,x]+b*(-g[0]+x*LaplaceTransform[g[t],t,x])==0,
c*(-f[0]+x*LaplaceTransform[f[t],t,x])+d*LaplaceTransform[g[t],t,x]==0}
```

Instead, however, `FourierTransform` of the same expression returns:

```
{FourierTransform[a*f[t]+b*g'[t]==0,t,x],FourierTransform[c*f'[t]+d*g[t]==0,t,x]}
```

## Edit

There is a solution to this problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/obtaining-the-fourier-transform-of-an-operator?rq=1), although it doesn't actually explain `FourierTransform`'s strange functionality.

Comment: To heIp you to understand the Edit post,it seems this is an unsove bug in addition of Laplace transform because FourierTransform[m x''[t], t, \[Omega]] + 
 FourierTransform[a  x'[t], t, \[Omega]] + 
 FourierTransform[K x[t], t, \[Omega]] - 
 FourierTransform[f[t], t, \[Omega]] works

Answer (score 15):

The easiest work-around I can think of is to write a "shell" for the current `FourierTransform`:

```
ft[(h : List | Plus | Equal)[a__], t_, w_] := ft[#, t, w] & /@ h[a]
ft[a_ b_, t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, Alternatives@@t] := b ft[a, t, w]
ft[a_, t_, w_] := FourierTransform[a, t, w]

ft[{a f[t] + b g'[t] == 0, c f'[t] + d e g[t] h[t] == 0}, t, w]
```

> ```
> {a FourierTransform[f[t], t, w] - I b w FourierTransform[g[t], t, w] == 0, 
>  -I c w FourierTransform[f[t], t, w] + d e FourierTransform[g[t] h[t], t, w]== 0}
> ```

Not sure if this will fail in more complicated cases.

---

In the code above I've only implemented the rules that are useful for solving differential equations, but it's not hard to include other properties of Fourier transform following the same method, for example:

```
(* Displacement property <- is this the right terminology? *)
ft[f_[t_] E^(Complex[0, c_] b_ t_), t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, t] := ft[f[t], t, w + c b]
(* Convolution property *)
ft[a_[t_] b_[t_], t_, w_] := 
  Module[{x}, Hold[Convolve][ft[a@t, t, x], ft[b@t, t, x], x, w]/Sqrt[2 Pi]]

ft[E^(-I t Ω) a[t], t, w]
```

> ```
> FourierTransform[a[t], t, w - Ω]
> ```

```
(* Verify the correctness: *)
FourierTransform[E^(-I t Ω) a[t], t, w] == % /. a -> (Exp[-#^2]&) // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
ft[a[t] b[t], t, w]
```

> ```
> (1/Sqrt[2 π]) Hold[Convolve][FourierTransform[a[t], t, x$60844], 
>  FourierTransform[b[t], t, x$60844], x$60844, w]
> ```

```
(* Verify the correctness: *)
% == FourierTransform[a[t] b[t], t, w] /. {a -> (Exp[-#^2] &), b -> (Exp[-3 #^2] &)} // 
  ReleaseHold // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

When dealing with high dimensional problem, the current behavior of `FourierTransform` is inconvenient:

```
FourierTransform[D[f[x, y], x, y], {x, y}, {wx, wy}]
(* -I wx FourierTransform[
          FourierTransform[Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y], x, wx], 
          y, wy] *)
```

What if I need

> ```
> -wx wy FourierTransform[f[x, y], {x, y}, {wx, wy}]
> ```

as the output? We can add the following rule:

```
ft[Derivative[i__][h_][var__], {t__}, {w__}] := 
 With[{truefalse = FreeQ[Alternatives@t] /@ {var} // Boole}, 
  Times @@ Pick[(-I {var})^{i}, truefalse, 0] ft[(Derivative @@ ({i} truefalse))[h][
     var], {t}, {w}]]

ft[a D[f[t, x, y], x, y] + b D[g[x, y], x, x] + c D[h[y], y], {x, y}, {wx, wy}]
```

> ```
>  -a x y FourierTransform[f[t, x, y], {x, y}, {wx, wy}] - 
>   b x^2 FourierTransform[g[x, y], {x, y}, {wx, wy}] - 
>   I c y FourierTransform[h[y], {x, y}, {wx, wy}]
> ```

---

Since *v12.3* we can also use `BilateralLaplaceTransform` instead of `FourierTransform`. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81164/1871) for more info.