# How do I let Fourier Transform know that it is a linear operator?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching, fourier-analysis

I have the following issue with FourierTransform, Fourier transform doesn't seem to know it is a linear operator.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
aa = FourierTransform[s1[t],t,omega];
bb = FourierTransform[s1'[t],t,omega];

cc = FourierTransform[s1[t] + s1'[t],t,omega];

Expand[aa+bb] == Expand[cc]
```

This yields false (more precisely, it doesn't yield true).  I would expect the Fourier transform to know it is a linear operator.  Do I have to do something like the following?

```
fourierTransformSubs = 
{
FourierTransform[a1_ f_[t_],t_,omega_] :>  a1 FourierTransform[f[t],t,omega],
FourierTransform[f_[t_]+g_[t_] ,t_,omega_] :> FourierTransform[f[t],t,omega] + 
                                              FourierTransform[g[t],t,omega]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Are you asking how to show the identity with `s[t]` defined or undefined?

Comment: s[t] is undefined.  I want to do things symbolically for now.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting question what should happen for the symbolic case. It's possible that a sum has a Fourier transform but its terms don't.

Comment: Hmmm, I have to think about that.  However is it possible that the Fourier transform of a function times a nonzero scalar exists, but the Fourier transform for the functions doesn't?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871