# FourierTransform a differental-equations

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I want to use the command `FourierTransform` to transform a  differential equations from time - domain to complex frequency domain but it don't works. My code is

```
    eq = {a'[t] == -κ/2 a[t] - I g b[t] E^(I Ω t) + 
    Sqrt[κ] ain , 
  b'[t] == -Γ/2 b[t] - I Ω b[t] - 
    I g a[t] E^(- I Ω t) + Sqrt[Γ] bin}
ff = FourierTransform[eq, t, ω]
```

The Result is

```
   (* {FourierTransform[
  Derivative[1][a][t] == 
   ain Sqrt[κ] - 1/2 κ a[t] - 
    I E^(I t Ω) g b[t], t, ω], 
 FourierTransform[
  Derivative[1][b][t] == 
   bin Sqrt[Γ] - I E^(-I t Ω) g a[t] - 
    1/2 Γ b[t] - I Ω b[t], t, ω]} *)
```

Then I try use Map to make it works

```
    Clear["Global`*"]
eq = {a'[t] == -κ/2 a[t] - I g b[t] E^(I Ω t) + 
    Sqrt[κ] ain , 
  b'[t] == -Γ/2 b[t] - I Ω b[t] - 
    I g a[t] E^(- I Ω t) + Sqrt[Γ] bin}
ff = FourierTransform[#, t, ω] &
Map[ff, eq, {2}]
```

But it doesn't work, either:

```
(*{-I ω FourierTransform[a[t],t,ω]==FourierTransform[ain Sqrt[κ]-1/2 κ a[t]-I E^(I t Ω) g b[t],t,ω],-I ω FourierTransform[b[t],t,ω]==FourierTransform[bin Sqrt[Γ]-I E^(-I t Ω) g a[t]-1/2 Γ b[t]-I Ω b[t],t,ω]}*)
```

How can I make *Mathematica* apply `FourierTransForm` in every term of a differential equation

With the method of [Workarounds for a possible bug in the linearity of FourierTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56237/workarounds-for-a-possible-bug-in-the-linearity-of-fouriertransform) I define a shell but it dosen't work well for some term.

```
(*Clear["Global`*"]
ft[(h : List | Plus | Equal)[a__], t_, w_] := ft[#, t, w] & /@ h[a]
ft[a_ b_, t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, t] := b ft[a, t, w]
ft[a_ E^(-I b_ t_) , t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, t] := ft[a + b, t, w]
ft[a_, t_, w_] := FourierTransform[a, t, w]
eq = { eq = {a'[t] == -κ/2 a[t] - I g b[t] E^(I Ω t) + 
        Sqrt[κ] ain , 
      b'[t] == -Γ/2 b[t] - I Ω b[t] - 
        I g a[t] E^(- I Ω t) + Sqrt[Γ] bin}}
ft[eq, t, ω]*)
```

Then I get a result

```
(*{-I ω FourierTransform[a[t],  t, ω] == -(1/2) κ FourierTransform[a[t],t,ω]+ Sqrt[κ] FourierTransform[ain[t], t, ω] - I g FourierTransform[E^(I t Ω) b[t], t, ω],                 -I ωFourierTransform[b[t], t, ω] == -I g FourierTransform[E^(-I t Ω) a[t], t,ω]- 1/2 Γ FourierTransform[b[t], t, ω] - I Ω FourierTransform[b[t], t, ω] +Sqrt[Γ] FourierTransform[bin[t], t, ω]}*)
```

The term "FourierTransform[
     E^(-I t Ω) a[t], t, ω]" is uncalculated. It is improper to direct added a "Times" command in the first shell. And even more, I wonder how can I deal with the nonlinear conditional with a term "a[t] b[t]" ?

Comment: Different from previous problem there is a term have the Command Times `a[t] E^(- I Ω t)` or even more I want to ask how to deal with the term `a[t]*b[t]` using mathematica. Must I write a shell according to the property of Fourier Transform by myself?

Comment: Yes, writing shell ourselves seems to be the only available solution currently. As to the `a[t] E^(- I Ω t)` term, except for the programming issue, you misremember the corresponding rule, in a word, it should be something like `ft[f_[t_] E^(Complex[0, c_] b_ t_), t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, t] := ft[f[t - c b], t, w]
`. Rule 109 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships) isn't hard to implement, too. But why you need them? as far as I can tell, these rules are just useless when solving differential equations.

Comment: Thx, I got it. It looks I should write the rule that I want to use by myself. Here I need the Rule 109 you mentioned. For, I am researching a nonlinear coupled system, and I should get some porperty of this system in frequency domain. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, just noticed I've made a mistake when implementing rule 103, it should be `ft[f_[t_] E^(Complex[0, c_] b_ t_), t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, t] := ft[f[t], t, w + c b]`

Comment: I just include rule 103 and 109 in the linked answer, have a look.

Comment: Thanks very much, It's just what I wanted. But I don't know what "x$60844" in your text mean? I can't find in the offical help

Comment: It's just a intermediate variable generated by `Module` and it'll disappear if `Convolve` is successfully calculated. Its role is the same as the $x$ in the formula $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x) g(y-x) \, dx$. If you don't like it and are not   in fear of duplication of variable name, you can take away the `Module` and the `x$…` will become `x` then.