# Solving the heat equation on the semi-infinite rod

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, boundary-condition-at-infinity

**Cross posted [in scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28082/5331).**

---

I want to test the solution which is given below is right by *Mathematica*.

Please look [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473201/how-to-solve-heat-equation-on-the-semi-infinite-rod-by-fourier-transform/2476391#2476391) in mathstackexhange

or

Please look below.

**Question:** Solve the following heat equation on the semi-infinite rod

$\qquad u_t=ku_{xx}$

where $x,t>0$ and

$\qquad u_x(0,t) =0$ and $u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 
          1, & 0 < x <2 \\
          0, &  2\leq x  
       \end{cases}$

with proper Fourier transform.

**Answer**

We found the following answer

$
\qquad u(x,t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-s^2 t}\frac{1-\cos(2s)}{s}\cos(sx)ds.
$

**Code**

But I am not sure the solution is right. I am not capable of testing it in *Mathematica*.

Could you help me?

Comment: I don't we can do much to help without having the code you used to get the answer. If you didn't use Mathematica to solve your problem, then this question is inappropriate -- I would mean you are asking us to both write the code and verify the solution for you.

Comment: Well, solving this in _Mathematica_ is quite straightforward, just check the document of `DSolve`. Anyway, the solution is `1/2 (-Erf[(-2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[k t])] + Erf[(2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[k t])])`. A quick test shows the solution in your question _seems_ to be wrong.

Comment: Further check shows that, if one wants to express the solution as integration, then it should be $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sin (2 w) e^{-k t w^2} \cos (w x)}{w} \, dw$

Comment: Guys, personally I suggest not to close this post, though it's a… "give me the code" question, the problem is interesting, I think.

Comment: Please do not cross-post within SE sites.  Choose *one* site and delete the questions from the others. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/164803

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I think the problem is interesting, so let me extend my comments to an answer. First of all, `DSolve` can solve OP's problem straightforwardly (in *Mathematica 10.3* or higher, if I remember correctly):

```
With[{u = u[t, x]}, 
 eq = D[u, t] == k D[u, x, x];
 ic = u == Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 2}}] /. t -> 0;
 bc = D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> 0;]

asol = DSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, x}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, k > 0}];
asol[t, x]
(* 1/2 (-Erf[(-2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[k] Sqrt[t])] + Erf[(2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[k] Sqrt[t])]) *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> There seems to be a bug in `DSolve` in *v11.2.0*.
>
> ```
> DSolve[{eq, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}]
> ```
>
> will return unevaluated.

As one can see, `DSolve` expresses the solution with `Erf`, so it's not immediately clear whether OP's solution is correct or not, and *Mathematica*'s functions for simplifying also doesn't work well in this case, so let's obtain the analytic solution with another approach, that is, making use of Fourier cosine transform to eliminate the derivative of $x$:

```
fct = FourierCosTransform[#, x, s] &;

tset = Map[fct, {eq, ic}, {2}] /. Rule @@ bc /. 
  HoldPattern@FourierCosTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol = u[t, x] /. DSolve[tset, u[t, x], t][[1]]
(* (E^(-k s^2 t) Sqrt[2/π] Sin[2 s])/s *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> I've made the transform on the PDE in a quick way, for a more general
>   approach, check [this
>   post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871).

`InverseFourierCosTransform` has difficulty in transforming `tsol`, but it doesn't matter because the integral form is just what we want. By checking the formula of inverse Fourier cosine transform, we find the solution should be

$$u(t,x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-k s^2 t} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \cos (s x) \sin (2 s)}{s} \, ds$$

It's apparently different from the one in your question, and numeric calculation shows this solution is the same as the one given by `DSolve`, so the one in your question is wrong.

Finally, a illustration for the solution:

```
Plot3D[asol[t, x] /. k -> 1 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 4}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

## Update

Inspired by [Ars3nous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10660/ars3nous)' comment below, I noticed `InverseFourierCosTransform` can actually transform `tsol`. We just need a proper assumption:

```
InverseFourierCosTransform[tsol, s, x, Assumptions -> k > 0]
(* 1/2 (-Erf[(-2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[k t])] + Erf[(2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[k t])]) *)
```

Apparently it's the same as `asol`.

Comment: Following @xzczd amazing answer using cosine transform, with k=1 (you can always scale out k in time)
In Mathematica 9.0, I get using *InverseFourierCosineTransform*,
$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 x \text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x+2}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)+\text{erfc}\left(-\frac{x-2}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)+\frac{4 \sqrt{t} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 t}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}-2\right)$
which has two different terms along the mentioned answer. But this solution also does not satisfy boundary conditions. I wonder what is the discrepency for.

Comment: @Ars3nous Are you in _v9.0.0_ or _v9.0.1_? I just tested in _v9.0.1_, _Win10 64bit_, with `InverseFourierCosTransform[tsol /. k -> 1, s, x]` I got `1/2 (Erf[(2 - x)/(2 Sqrt[t])] + Erf[(2 + x)/(2 Sqrt[t])])`, which is consistent with `asol`.