# For Fourier Transform with $ x(t) $, how to obtain result in terms of $ X(f) $?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis

I have a function $ x(t) $ and I denoted its Fourier transformation as $ X(f) $. I want to get the Fourier transformation of $ x(t)\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i \pi f_0 t} $, and I know the result is $ X(f-f_0) $.

I tried to obtain this result by using Mathematica, but didn't obtain `X[f-f0]` as output:-

```
X[f] := FullSimplify@FourierTransform[x[t], t, f, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]
FullSimplify@FourierTransform[x[t]*Exp[2 I \[Pi] f0 t], t, f, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]
```

How can I obtain `X[f-f0]` as output?

Thanks!

Comment: `FourierTransform` just can't do that, but we can write a "shell" for it. Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871

Comment: Thanks for your help. The shell helps a lot! I applied convolution properties etc. Just 1 issue, how can I obtain `A[w-w0]` instead of `FourierTransform[a[t], t, w - w0, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]}]` as output?

Comment: Try something like this: `ft[x[t] Exp[2 I Pi f0 t], t, s] /. 
 HoldPattern@FourierTransform[f_[x_], _, s_] :> Symbol[ToUpperCase@ToString@f][s]`. BTW, personally I recommend not to rewrite `a` as `A` i.e. `ft[x[t] Exp[2 I Pi f0 t], t, s] /. HoldPattern@FourierTransform[f_[x_], _, s_] :> f[s]`, just keep in mind now `x` actually represents $X$, this usually makes programming easier.