# Difference between FourierTransform and LaplaceTransform

Tags: differential-equations, integral-transforms

There is an equation for example：

```
eqn=D[c[x, t], t] == d D[c[x, t], x, x];
```

When I make a LaplaceTransform of it:

```
LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s]
```

Then mathematica will impose the transform to both sides of the '=', and the result will be :

```
s*LaplaceTransform[c[x, t], t, s] - c[x, 0] == d*LaplaceTransform[Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t], t, s]
```

But when I make a FourierTransform it won't do that, and the output :

```
FourierTransform[Derivative[0, 1][c][x, t] == d*Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t], t, \[Omega]]
```

And I just wonder know why. What's the difference？

Comment: BTW a workaround can be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56237/1871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only difference is that some developer told `LaplaceTransform` to do so while it came to nobody's mind to do the same for  `FourierTransform`. So, no deep mathematics behind that.

If you like, you can add a the following definition to `FourierTransform`:

```
Unprotect[FourierTransform];
FourierTransform[eq_Equal, args__] := FourierTransform[#, args] & /@ eq;
Protect[FourierTransform];
```

Then you obtain

```
FourierTransform[Derivative[0, 1][c][x, t] == d*Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t], t, ω]
```

> (-I)*ω*FourierTransform[c[x, t], t, ω] == 
>    FourierTransform[d*Derivative[2, 0][c][x, t], t, ω]