# LaplaceTransform works well with x[t], but doesn't recognize x[1][t], how to make it works for x[1][t]?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, integral-transforms

**Bug introduced in 12.2(?), persisting through 14.0 or later.**

---

When I am solving odes using LaplaceTransform, I found that `LaplaceTransform` works well with u[t] or y[t] or x[t], but doesn't recognize x[1][t].

**So, how to make `LaplaceTransform` know x[1][t]?**

Thanks.

```
In[125]:= LaplaceTransform[a x[t] + b y'[t], t, s] // Simplify

Out[125]= 
a LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s] + b s LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s] - 
 b y[0]

In[126]:= LaplaceTransform[a x[1][t] + b x[2]'[t], t, s] // Simplify

Out[126]= LaplaceTransform[a x[1][t] + b Derivative[1][x[2]][t], t, s]
```

Comment: Simpler fix: `LaplaceTransform[#, t, s] & /@ (a x[1][t] + b x[2]'[t])`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously a bug. (If I guess it right, it's introduced in *v12.2* together with [this bug](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56607155#56607155). ) *v9.0.1* gives the desired result:

[image]

A possible fix is turning to the method mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871):

```
Unprotect@LaplaceTransform;
LaplaceTransform[(h : Plus)[a__], t_, w_] := LaplaceTransform[#, t, w] & /@ h[a]
Protect@LaplaceTransform;
```