# Nice output for FourierTransform

Tags: fourier-analysis, format

I want to demonstrate `FourierTransform` in a lecture. However if you give `FourierTransform` a differential equation it does not know about linearity and just returns the answer.

```
e = x''[t] + 2 z w0 x'[t] + w0^2 x[t] == g[t];
FourierTransform[e, t, w]
```

[image]

Which is not much help. Fortunately, @xzczd has developed this [shell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/12558) to provide standard rules. This is implemented by

```
ClearAll[FT];
FT[(h : List | Plus | Equal)[a__], t_, w_] := FT[#, t, w] & /@ h[a]
FT[a_ b_, t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, Alternatives @@ t] := b FT[a, t, w]
FT[a_, t_, w_] := FourierTransform[a, t, w]
```

This now works on the differential equation thus

```
FT[e, t, w]
```

[image]

However I would like to take this one step further by using the convention that lower case letters in the time domain give rise to capital letters in the frequency domain. I can do this for specific cases using replacement rules as follows.

```
ClearAll[FT];
FT[(h : List | Plus | Equal)[a__], t_, w_] := FT[#, t, w] & /@ h[a]
FT[a_ b_, t_, w_] /; FreeQ[b, Alternatives @@ t] := b FT[a, t, w]
FT[a_, t_, w_] := 
 FourierTransform[a, t, w] /. {FourierTransform[x[t], t, w] -> X[w], 
   FourierTransform[g[t], t, w] -> G[w]}
```

This gives the form I want

```
sol = FT[e, t, w]

(* -w^2 X[w] + w0^2 X[w] - 2 I w w0 z X[w] == G[w] *)
```

One can now do further operations such as

```
Solve[sol, X[w]]


(* {{X[w] -> -(G[w]/(w^2 - w0^2 + 2 I w w0 z))}}*)
```

However, it is specific to the symbols of `x[t]` and `g[t]` I have implimented. Can this be done so that any lower case letter, e.g. a in the form `FourierTransform[a[t], t, w]` goes to `A[w]`?

Comment: Would something like this work? `FourierTransform[op_[t_], t_, w_] :> 
 Symbol@*Capitalize@*ToString@*op@w`, in place of `{FourierTransform[x[t], t, w] -> X[w], 
   FourierTransform[g[t], t, w] -> G[w]}`?  If so, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @march I Can' get it to work.  I get a RuleDelayed error if I apply it as a rule.  Would a `Format` statement work?

Comment: @march If I write it as `{FourierTransform[op_[t_], t_, w_] :> 
  Symbol[Capitalize[ToString[op]]][w]}`  then it gives a warning but works. Please post your answer.

Comment: Just to compare. `e = x''[t] + 2 z w0 x'[t] + w0^2 x[t] == g[t];
LaplaceTransform[e, t, w]` results in `w^2 LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, w] + 
  w0^2 LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, w] + 
  2 w0 z (w LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, w] - x[0]) - w x[0] - 
  Derivative[1][x][0] == LaplaceTransform[g[t], t, w]`. As far as I know it, `LaplaceTransfom` is more often used for solving linear ODEs.

Comment: @user64494 I agree the Laplace transform is much better for symbolic work with ODEs. However, I am starting with the Fourier transform and moving towards numerical Laplace transforms. So there is a logic to my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a replacement rule that works in general, we use the `String` function `Capitalize`, like so:

```
FourierTransform[op_[t_], t_, w_] :> (Symbol@Capitalize@ToString@op)@w
```